# SQLite UPDATE WHERE perfomance

Tags: android, database, performance, android-sqlite, android-room

Let's say that I do have following DB table named `LogTable`

```
id  name  show
O    A    false
1    B    true
2    C    true
```

This table can easily hold up to 100k entries. Now I want to update all of the entries to hold `show` column value as `true`. My first attempt was:

```
@Query("UPDATE LogTable SET `show` = $FALSE WHERE `show` = $TRUE")
```

This worked, until my colleague did point out that we can theoretically omit the `WHERE` clause to improve performance eg.

```
 @Query("UPDATE LogTable SET `show` = $FALSE)
```

And to my big surprise it works better no matter what kind of data I mock. At least I though that when we will have more `show = FALSE` the query with `WHERE` clause would be better in terms of performance.

What am I missing ? Does WHERE add in this particular case unnecessary overhead as it needs to find the entries first ?